# What type of phrase is "site by site"?

Tags: phrases

In the sentence "You can search site by site," what type of phrase is "site by site"? And am I correct in thinking that it does not need hyphens in that particular sentence?

Comment: When you say, "what type of phrase", are you asking for a grammatical category? If so then it's an adverbial phrase modifying the verb "search". Or are you asking something else?

Comment: Yes, I was asking for a grammatical category :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can search *quickly*.

Here, *quickly* is an adverb that modifies *search*.

> You can search **site by site**.

In the same way, **site by site** is an adverbial *phrase* that modifies *search*. (It describes *how* you will search.)

---

Compound adjectives used in front of nouns are commonly (although not always) hyphenated:

> It is a **site-by-site** search.

However, when a compound adjective comes after a noun, the hyphenation is normally dropped:

> The search is **site by site**.

In your example sentence, **site by site** not only comes afterwards, but it's being used adverbially rather and adjectivally.